# Dj rest auth and allauth returning wrong email format

Tags: python, django, email, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I'm building an API using DJ rest auth and allauth for registration and login. I customized the email format for registration using custom adapters. Whenever I test it out in localhost it returns the desired email format which is:

```
Dear TestUser1,


Welcome to Ekopages, your gateway to sustainable education!


We're thrilled to have you join our community. To get started on your journey towards a greener future, please click the link below to confirm your email address:

https://ekopages.com/registration/account-confirm-email/NTE:1rUpCQ:qimz8K0QFUD5ZM8WbMlmcBqq3HSzNp0vNSziMaJRV44/

Once confirmed, you'll have full access to ekopages.com, where learning meets sustainability.





Thank you for choosing Ekopages. Let's embark on this educational adventure together!


Green regards,
The EkoPages Team.
ekopages.com
```

after I deploy it though it just returns a format that i didnt add

```
Hello from !





Dear testuser,
Welcome to Ekopages, your gateway to sustainable education!

We're thrilled to have you join our community. To get started on your
journey towards a greener future, please click the link below to
confirm your email address:

https://ekopages.com/registration/account-confirm-email/NjI:1rWQ5A:ZKz5BArUgGzhT8tP8KKIuV62vGdVzBQ3blPHALsxWAE/

Once confirmed, you'll have full access to ekopages.com, where
learning meets sustainability.





Thank you for using !
```

I customized the registration and adapters too so I dont know where the hello from! is coming from

```
#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

  def _create_user(self, username, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, address, **extra_fields):
    now = timezone.now()
    if not username:
      raise ValueError(('The given username must be set'))
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
             is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
             is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
             date_joined=now, address=address, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

  def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, False, False, True,
                 **extra_fields)

  def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
    user=self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True,
                 **extra_fields)
    user.is_active=True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, default='username')
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='Pictures', blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #subscription_start_dates = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    #subscription_end_dates = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    def get_full_name(self):
      return self.email 
    def get_short_name(self):
      return self.email
    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.email
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
      return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
      return True
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
      return self.is_admin
```

```
#serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from allauth.account import app_settings as allauth_settings
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from allauth.account.utils import setup_user_email
from allauth.socialaccount.helpers import complete_social_login
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.base import AuthProcess
from allauth.utils import email_address_exists, get_username_max_length
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import UserDetailsSerializer
from .models import User


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)

    password1 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)


    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email and email_address_exists(email):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    ("A user is already registered with this e-mail address."))
        return email

    def validate_password1(self, password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password1'] != data['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                ("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return data

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'first_name': self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
            'last_name': self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),

        }
    
    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])


        first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')

        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name        

        user.save()
        return user


class UserDetailsSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ['username','email','profile_picture','first_name', 'last_name'] #'subscription_start_dates', 'subscription_end_dates']
        read_only_fields = ['username','email',]#' subscription_end_dates', 'subscription_start_dates'
        model = User
```

```
#settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Account.User'

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'Account.serializers.RegisterSerializer'
}
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'Account.serializers.UserDetailsSerializer',
}

#adapters.py

from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.urls import reverse

from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def send_confirmation_mail(self, request, emailconfirmation, signup):
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        activate_url = reverse(
            "account_confirm_email",
            args=[emailconfirmation.key],
        )
        activate_url = "https://ekopages.com" + activate_url
        ctx = {
            "user": emailconfirmation.email_address.user,
            "activate_url": activate_url,
            "site_name": current_site.name,
            "site_domain": current_site.domain,
        }
        subject = render_to_string("templates/account/email_subject.txt", ctx)
        subject = subject.strip()
        email_body = render_to_string("templates/account/email_message.txt", ctx)

        msg = EmailMessage(subject, email_body, to=[emailconfirmation.email_address.email])
        msg.send()


#email message body

{% extends "account/email/base_message.txt" %}
{% load account %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
{% autoescape off %}
{% user_display user as user_display %}
{% blocktrans with site_name="EkoPages" site_domain="ekopages.com" %}
Dear {{ user_display }},
Welcome to Ekopages, your gateway to sustainable education!

We're thrilled to have you join our community. To get started on your journey towards a greener future, please click the link below to confirm your email address:

{{ activate_url }}

Once confirmed, you'll have full access to {{ site_domain }}, where learning meets sustainability.

{% endblocktrans %}
{% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
```

I dont see what is wrong. Please any help would be appreciated